# Odd behavior with integration in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, integral

I find that the SymPy integrate function gives very different answers depending on how I multiply the argument of the integral by a constant.  I don't understand this.  Multiplication by a constant should be a trivial factor in front of the integral and I wouldn't expect it to modify the result. Here is an example

```
from sympy import *
h,y  = symbols('h y')
expr = h**(1)*y**2/(1+y**2)**2
print('Integral * h')
print(integrate(expr,y))
expr = h**(-1)*y**2/(1+y**2)**2
print('Integral / h')
print(integrate(expr,y))
```

Which gives output

```
Integral * h
h*(-y/(2*y**2 + 2) + atan(y)/2)
Integral / h
-y/(2*h*y**2 + 2*h) + (-I*log(y - I)/4 + I*log(y + I)/4)/h
```

I would expect the second case to just give

```
Integral * h
h**(-1) *(-y/(2*y**2 + 2) + atan(y)/2)

I realize the two answers are mathematically equivalent but why should multiplying by a constant change which form is displayed?
```

Comment: Sometimes routines do not handle rational expression as well as expressions without a denominator. The same applies to real and imaginary parts. SymPy tries to use `simplify` sparingly, leaving the tidying up of an expression to the caller (e.g. with `simplify`).

Comment: If the symbols are declared with `real=True` you will get both in terms of `atan`.